# How to create a project from the commandline?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to create an IntelliJ project purely from the command line?

We are looking a streamlining the on-boarding of new hires and off-shore resources and to minimise the amount of project setup they have to perform. As such, it would be nice if we had the IDE already configured for them to get started.

Comment: Did you consider to use Gradle or Maven? IntelliJ IDEA can open the build files and perform the import.

Comment: @CrazyCoder we do use Maven, it's triggering that import that I am trying to do programmatically so that when the new user fires up the IDE for the first time it's not blank.

Comment: Just instruct the users to import `pom.xml` files, there is no way to trigger project generation via the command line without user interaction.

Comment: Well that was the question. Might look at the `.iml` file format and see what I can learn.

Comment: There is a legacy plug-in for Maven, but we don't recommend using it: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/usage.html.

Comment: That would make for a fine answer ;) *cough*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [legacy plug-in for Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/usage.html) to generate IntelliJ IDEA project files, but we don't recommend using it.

Instead, it would be easier to instruct users to open `pom.xml` file in the IDE so that the import is performed automatically.